# How to order JTable columns to original position after being draged

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable and I want to give the users the possibility to position the columns as they want for a custom view of the information. But at the same time I'm needing a function (or an algorithm) to set these columns to it's original position when an specific event occurs.

I know that when you want to access to the data in a cell, the index of the column will still remain the same no matter on what position the user have set it.

For example: a JTable with 3 columns, let's say column1, column2, column3. If the user drags them to be displayed as column2, column3, column1, then column1 will still have the 0 index. So there must be a way to easily reordering them back to it's original position. I know that to access to the reordering of a column you need to get the header.

```
JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
header.setReorderingAllowed(true);
```

So from there I looked at the documentation of JTableHeader class but I didn't find anything useful, neither by searching an specific solution. I hope I have explained properly this problem. This is a similar example of my code.

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
table = new JTable(model);
model.addColumn(column1);
model.addColumn(column2);
model.addColumn(column3);
JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
header.setReorderingAllowed(true);


JButton button = new JButton("Reorder");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     //the code that orders the columns to its original position         
   }
};
```

Also I know that by default the reordering of the columns is set as true, but I added it to make it clear and to know what else I could add or do from there.

**EDIT 1**
first solution, using a `private static int[] ColumnsWidth` Array in a custom class called `HelperArrays` with the width of the columns as I need, in which the getter method returns the int used for the width of the each column, setting as parameter the index of the Array. We can reset the DefaultTableModel from the JTable Object but will be needed to also reset the widths of the columns in order to succesfully reorder columns to their original position

```
  private static int[] columnsWidhth = {widht1, widhth2, width3};

  public static int getColumnsWidth(int index){
  returns ColumnsWidth[index];
  }
```

---

```
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
      table.setModel(model);
      DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
      centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
          table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setMinWidth(HelperArrays.getColumnsWidth(i));
          table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setMaxWidth(HelperArrays.getColumnsWidth(i));
          table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(HelperArrays.getColumnsWidth(i));      
      }
  }
```

**EDIT 2**
Second and final solution, reordering the columns directly with the `moveColumn()` function from the `TableColumnModel` Object, using a loop to restore them by their original index.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    TableModel model = table.getModel();
    TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount() - 1; i++) {
            int location = tcm.getColumnIndex(model.getColumnName(i));
            tcm.moveColumn(location, i);
   }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So from there I looked at the documentation of JTableHeader

The information about how the `TableColumn`s are display is contained in the `TableColumnModel`.

You can just use the `moveColumn(...)` method to restore the column order.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableColumnRestore2 extends JFrame
{
    public TableColumnRestore2()
    {
        final JTable table = new JTable(5, 8);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane= new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        JButton restore = new JButton("Restore Columns");
        getContentPane().add(restore, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        restore.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                TableModel model = table.getModel();
                TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();

                for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount() - 1; i++)
                {
                    int location = tcm.getColumnIndex( model.getColumnName(i) );
                    tcm.moveColumn(location, i);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TableColumnRestore2 frame = new TableColumnRestore2();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just got one wonder about this. Why did you use the the `model.getColumnCount() - 1` in the loop? I tried without it and it didn't work, for what I know that function should return a 3 in a 3 columns table, so if I have to use the -1 then that means that it's returning a 4. Why is that?

Comment: @Pancho, If you have a 3 column table then you only need to reorder the first 2 columns. Then by default the 3rd column will already be in the proper position.

Comment: @camickr Ok, so I got the logic on that. But still I don't get why I get this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Identifier not found`  I mean, I get that it's not a need to relocate the last column, but if the loop doesn't have the -1 should work anyway, even if the last column would have to be "unnecessarily" moved  to it's current position at that moment of the loop.

Comment: @Pancho, Did you make the change to my posted code or your application code? It works fine for me if I remove the "- 1" from my posted code. I can't guess why your application code would not work.

Comment: @camickr I did on my code, but with what you just said I got why it didn't worked in mine, and it's because I completelly forgot that the last column in my table is hidden since it saves the id from the database on wich retrieves the information to be displayed. So that being said, the -1 actually saved my ass here because made it work at first try Lmao

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware if there is a better solution, but this seems to work:

```
TableModel model = table.getModel();
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
table.setModel(model);
```

A full example:

```
public class TableColumnOrderTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
            dm.addColumn("Column 1");
            dm.addColumn("Column 2");
            dm.addColumn("Column 3");
            dm.addColumn("Column 4");

            Object[][] data = { 
                    { "1", "Something","hello","World" }, { "102", "Something Else" }, 
                    { "55", "Something","dfsdf","fsdafas" }, { "66", "Something" },
                    { "1000", "Something" }, { "1524", "Something" }, 
                    { "5801", "Something" }, { "-55", "Something" },};

            for (Object[] row : data) {
                dm.addRow(row);
            }
            JTable table = new JTable(dm);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));

            JButton button = new JButton("button");
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
                table.setModel(dm);
            });

            panel.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
        });
    }
}
```

**Preview:**

[image]

### EDIT

Recently I asked [how to restore column widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346826/how-to-restore-column-widths-in-a-jtable). Removing and re-adding the model will whack the renderers of the table. You can use something like the following in case you use custom `TableCellRenderers` and you want to preserve them after re-setting the model:

```
private static void restoreColumnOrdering(JTable table) {
    TableModel model = table.getModel();
    Map<Object, TableCellRenderer> renderers = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Object, Integer> widths = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = column.getCellRenderer();
        renderers.put(column.getIdentifier(), cellRenderer);
        widths.put(column.getIdentifier(), column.getPreferredWidth());
    }

    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
    table.setModel(model);

    // Reset renderers
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = renderers.get(column.getIdentifier());
        column.setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
        column.setPreferredWidth(widths.get(column.getIdentifier()));
    }
}
```

Comment: So it worked to reorder the columns as I wanted but it did indeed set to default the width of the columns. I'm not using the TableCellRenderer, but I do use the DefaultTableCellRenderer, and only as a local variable to set a center aligment of the headers.
`DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();` 
 

`centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);`

 `((DefaultTableCellRenderer)header.getDefaultRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);`

Comment: @Pancho I have updated my answer. A `DefaultTableCellRenderer` is a `TableCellRenderer` since it `implements` this interface.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but before I read this I came with a similar solution to the width problem, I had a static final array with the width of my columns wich I used to set it on the initialization of the components. So I used that again in the action listener of the button. Unfortunately so far I'm not familiar with HashMap so that is kinda messy for me right now but it helped a lot anyway. I'll edit original post with what I've done so far

Comment: despite that, I'm not sure if this is good for ram performance in long terms, either your solution as mine.

Comment: @Pancho Having a constant array with the widths is obviously more clear than my way. But my way is more generalized, and it is more "reusable". Whatever, did you solve your problem? P.S: I would consider the "ram performance" negligible.

Comment: Yes I did solved it, thanks a lot. Also if you say that I should not concern about the ram performance then that's good, I'm kinda obssesive with that. Anyway I would like to implement your method but wihout using the HashMap as I'm not familiar with it. I think that I would make a function to set this columns width setting to re use it since I would have to use it in other situations.

Comment: @GeorgeZ., *Removing and re-adding the model will whack the renderers of the table* - if you are refreshing the data in a TableModel, that is the columns will remain the same, then after initially creating the table using your model you can use: `table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel​(falsel)`. This will prevent the TableColumnModel from being created so you won't lose your custom renderers/editors. Only the data in the model will change.